# Performance issue with access to excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, adodb

I need to get data from Access to excel vba, I use ADODB.
My problem is that although the database is relatively small and query results 30-40 records only, the process gets stuck either with the ".open" or with "copyfromrecordset" line and takes 40-50 secs to display the records.
This is my code.
I made some tests with different cursor types and locktypes with no result. The query is working executed directly from access and I have no issue when the connection points locally to my PC. I am on office 365. I referenced the activex data objects 2.8 library.

```
 Sub loadTestDisplay2()
    Dim myConnectiom As ADODB.Connection
    Dim myRS As ADODB.Recordset
    Const conStringNet As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\ourserver-f04\COE-Shared\Data Tool\Access\adsLoadTest.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;"

    Dim sql As String
    sql = "SELECT * FROM tblLoad where user is Null"

    Set myConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    Set myRS = New ADODB.Recordset

    myConnection.ConnectionString = conStringNet
    myConnection.Open

    With myRS
        .ActiveConnection = conStringNet
        .Source = sql
        .LockType = adLockReadOnly
        .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        .Open
    End With

    Sheets.Add
    Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset myRS

    myRS.Close
    myConnection.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `addSupData`?  Seems to me you should replace it with `myRS`.

Comment: You've already opened a connection object, so use it here: `Set .ActiveConnection = myConnection`  When you gave it a connection *string*, a new connection was created instead of using the one you already opened.

Comment: HansUp, thanks, in the working one this is not the case, just made some cleaning and I was not thorough enough, but I use the recordset which is created.